# How to count results from groupped subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such **SupplierLangs** table:
*ID, SupplierId, SrcLngId, TrgLngId*

it contains data like this:

```
1, 1000, 1, 2
2, 1000, 1, 3
3, 1000, 1, 4
4, 1000, 2, 3
5, 1000, 2, 4
6, 1001, 1, 2
7, 1001, 1, 4
8, 1001, 2, 4
9, 1002, 3, 4
```

when **Languages** table look like this:
*ID, LangName*

```
1, En
2, De
3, Fr
4, Pl
```

it means that supplier:
1000 can translate between:

```
En -> De
En -> Fr
En -> Pl
De -> FR
DE -> pl
```

1001 can translate between:

```
En -> De
En -> Pl
De -> Pl
```

1002 can translate between:

```
Fr -> Pl
```

I need a result showing me how many suppliers translate in given src languages:
LangId Count

```
1      2      (1000, 1001)
2      2      (1000, 1001)
3      1      (1002)
4      0      (no one translate from polish)
```

What I achieve is only count how many Suppliers translate in hard coded language:

```
select count(distinct SupplierId) from SupplierLangs
where SupplierId in
(
select sr.SupplierId  from SupplierLangs sr
where sr.SrcLngId = 1
group by sr.SupplierId
)
```

With above data return 2 (two suppliers translate from english)
But how to extend that for all languages to achieve results as mentioned above ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found proper query ( but I use temporary table ) - is it a solution without it ?

```
select distinct sr.SrcLngId, sr.SupplierId
into #myTable99
from SupplierLangs sl

select SrcLngId, count(SrcLngId) as [count] from #myTable99 temp
group by SrcLngId

drop table #myTable99
```

Thanks all for theirs reply!

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT supplierid) 
FROM   supplierlangs 
WHERE  supplierid IN (SELECT sr.supplierid 
                      FROM   supplierlangs sr 
                      --where sr.SrcLngId = 1 --Remove this 
                      GROUP  BY sr.supplierid) 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT supplierid)  > 0 --this will remove the record having no translation
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it is not what I need - it gives me only total count - one number. I need result as mentioned in my question: "LangId, Count" for all available languages

Answer (score 0):

That should give you a list with source-language, target language and how many suppliers translate.

without joins:

```
SELECT  SrcLngId, TrgLngId, count(*) FROM SupplierLangs 
GROUP BY SrcLngId, TrgLngId
```

with joins:

```
SELECT L_SRC.ID, L_TRG.ID, COUNT(*)  FROM SupplierLangs 
INNER JOIN Languages AS L_SRC ON L_SRC.ID = SupplierLangs.SrcLngId
INNER JOIN Languages AS L_TRG ON L_TRG.ID = SupplierLangs.TrgLngId
GROUP BY L_SRC.ID, L_SRC.ID
```

you could create a view from it.

this will filter a single language

```
SELECT L_SRC.ID, L_SRC.ID, COUNT(*)  FROM SupplierLangs 
INNER JOIN Languages AS L_SRC ON L_SRC.ID = SupplierLangs.SrcLngId
INNER JOIN Languages AS L_TRG ON L_TRG.ID = SupplierLangs.TrgLngId
WHERE SupplierLangs.SrcLngId = 1
GROUP BY L_SRC.ID, L_SRC.ID
```

you should have a unique constraint on SupplierId, SrcLngId, TrgLngId for SupplierLangs (if you dont have already) to avoid having any data twice.

**/edit:**
that should work:

```
SELECT SupplierSrc.SrcLngId, count(*) FROM
(
  SELECT distinct SupplierId, SrcLngId FROM SupplierLangs AS SupplierSrc
)
GROUP BY SupplierSrc.SrcLngId
```

Comment: Thank you for your complex reply! Unfortunately it does not what I am looking for. The third snipet ( after removing TrgLang ) gives proper "Structure" = "SrcLngId, count", but in count inumbers are wrong. As mentioned in my question, for example for SrcLangId = 1 ( En ) count should be 2, because two suppliers (1000 and 1001) can translate from it - it does not mine for how many trgLang. Above query whould return for such data 5 (instead of two)- because there are 5 rows with SrcLang = 1

Comment: Thank you for your answer! on my SqlServer 2012 it does not parse correctly - it underline errors on Group by: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP' expecting AS ID, or QUOTED_ID and SupplierSrc.SrcLngId : the multi-part identifier could not be found

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a result with ALL languages and the count of suppliers who can translate from these languages, then you don't need a slow sub-query for this. You only need joins and grouping features. See the query below:

```
select SrcLngId, count(distinct supplierid) from SupplierLangs 
group by SrcLngId
```

That's a neat optimized query

Hope it helps

Leo

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This give me proper "structure" of result ("SrcLngId, count") but numbers in count columns are wrong. As mentioned in my question, for example for SrcLangId = 1 ( En ) count should be 2, because two suppliers (1000 and 1001) can translate from it - it does not mine for how many trgLang. Above query whould return for such data 5 (instead of two)- because there are 5 rows with SrcLang = 1

Comment: My bad! But the fix is even easier. Just stick a DISTINCT keyword in the count function and you'll get what you want. I've edited the sql query in my answer

Comment: Thank you for fix. But it still does not give results as I expected - compare with my own answer.

Comment: ??? This query returns the counts of supplier who translate from a specific language.  Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "still not giving the results expected"?